# Android Textview became black

Tags: java, android, textview

I don't know what happened. 
I changed graddle and updated my google-services.json file. Nothing serious.

After couple of builds i noticed, that all TextView in my app became black. I mean black text color. It doesn't matters what color will you choose in xml, text will be black. If you'll set it programmatically it will change, but with xml no chances.

No Java code changes was made. Do you have any ideas what happened. Thank a lot. 
Project is very big and setting all textfield's color programmaticaly will take to much time and will decrease application speed.
Thank you very much.

My gradle files

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {

        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.ykemer.autogeorgia"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

Second one

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}




allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://repo.commonsware.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: In your styles.xml try to add the line   <item name="android:textColor">#124578</item> inside your app theme and check

Comment: This would change every text to this color. Must be some graddle update error, had the same issue yesterday and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: what changes you made from the previous build ? Check your backup files so that you can find any issues there

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in your **styles.xml's** **AppTheme**

```
<item name="android:textColor">Desired Color Code</item>
```

and let me know if it work for you